# UISlider needs to have a range 1-5 and align it self to nearest notch

Tags: ios, uislider

I have 4 UISliders that need to have values from 1-5 with 1 being the minimum value and 5 the maximum.

I have set up the sliders and call them slider1, slider2, slide3, slider4

I have also set up the outlets etc and set the minimum and maximum values in interface builder

However when I scroll the slider it just slides instead of sticking to the 1-5 scale.

I have attempted the following and am failing miserably as I saw this at some other SO question

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{

    [sender setValue:((int)((sender getValue] + 2.5) / 5) * 5) animated:NO];

}
```

UPDATED: This seems to work as a solution

```
   - (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{

    NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)([sender value] + 0.5); // Round the number.
    [sender setValue:index animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"index: %i", index);

 //   NSNumber *number = [numbers objectAtIndex:index]; // <-- This is the number you want.
 //   NSLog(@"number: %@", number);

}
```

can you help me with this? I am getting an error with the getValue function also above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C ain't Java, the naming convention for getters is different. Use `value` instead of `getValue` (and anyways, why don't you declare `sender` as `UISlider *`?)

Comment: @kratos Yep, give the compiler as much hints as possible, both of you will have less headache.